# How do I display Kendo Grid inside Kendo Grid cell?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo Grid in my MVC application to display data. It works perfectly fine. But I would like to show another grid inside grid cell. I have done my research and tried different things, but I didn't find any solution. Please suggest.
Here is my code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeSheetManagement.Models.ClientView>()
.Name( "Clients" )
.Columns( columns =>
{
    columns.Bound( e => e.Name );
    columns.Bound( e => e.Address );
    columns.Bound( e => e.City );
    columns.Bound( e => e.State );
    columns.Bound( e => e.ZipCode );
    columns.Template( e => e.Contacts ).ClientTemplate( "#= buildContactsGrid(data) #" );
    columns.Bound( e => e.CreatedDate );
    columns.Bound( e => e.CreatedBy );
    columns.Bound( e => e.UpdatedDate );
    columns.Bound( e => e.UpdatedBy );
    columns.Bound( "" ).ClientTemplate( @Html.ActionLink( "Edit" , "Create" , new { clientId = "#=Id#" } , new { title = "Edit Client" } ).ToHtmlString() );
} )
.Pageable().Sortable().Filterable()
.AutoBind( true )
.DataSource( source => source.Ajax()
                    .PageSize( 20 )
                    .Read( read => read.Action( "GetClients" , "Client" ) )
    )
)
```

Here is my JavaScript function.

```
<script>

    function buildContactsGrid(client)
    {
        var htmlContacts = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action( "GetJsonContactsByClientId" )',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'sClientId': client.Id
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                htmlContacts += "<table style='border:1px solid black;'><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Role</th></tr><tr>";
                $(response).each(function (index, item) {
                    htmlContacts +="<td>"+ item.FirstName +"</td><td>"+ item.LastName+"</td><td>"+item.Role +"</td></tr>";
                });
                htmlContacts += "</table>";
            }
        });
        return htmlContacts;
    }
</script>
```

I was able to build a table in JavaScript function and display in grid cell, but I would like to display Kendo Grid.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spent some days on google by doing some research, I found this post [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/numeric-textbox-in-grid), they explained why client template not being bound on load.

Here is my grid inside grid cell:

```
columns.Template( e => "" ).Title("Contacts").ClientTemplate( 
        Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeSheetManagement.Models.ContactView>()
           .Name( "Clients_#=Id#" )
           .Columns( c =>
           {
               c.Bound( e1 => e1.FullName );
               c.Bound( e1 => e1.Role );
               c.Bound( e1 => e1.Email );
               c.Bound( e1 => e1.PhoneNumber );

            } )
            .AutoBind( true )
            .DataSource( source1 => source1.Ajax()
            .PageSize( 5 )
            .Read( read1 => read1.Action( "GetContactsByClientId" , "Client" , new { sClientId = "#=Id#" } ) )
            )
            .ToClientTemplate()
            .ToHtmlString()
        );
```

And I have this event on the grid.

```
  .Events( e => e.DataBound( "onGridDataBound" ) )
```

And finally I added this code in the script.

```
 function onGridDataBound(e)
    {
        $('#Clients script').appendTo(document.body);
    }
```

Here is the output as I expected. Let me know if you have any questions.
[image]